# Push TemplateRef into object

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-template

**Goal:** Dynamically push references to `ng-template`s into an object.

**Challenge:**

1. I'm manually creating a `@ViewChild` for *each*  `ng-template` reference.
2. I am not sure  how to push each  `@ViewChild` into my `data` object.

```
//Parent TS Component

export type ITabData = object[];

@Component({
    selector: 'app-style-guide',
    templateUrl: './style-guide.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./style-guide.component.scss']
})
export class StyleGuideComponent implements OnInit {

// These are a couple <ng-templates> I'm referencing. But as some point we can have many more templates.

    @ViewChild('orderDetails') orderDetails: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ViewChild('anotherTemp') anotherTemp: TemplateRef<any>;

   // My Data object that I want to push all the ViewChild to.

    data: ITabData = [];

    constructor () {
        // I'm pretty sure this is incorrect since it did not work

        this.data.push({ tabLabel: 'newlabel', template: this.orderDetails });
    }

    ngOnInit () {

        // This is how I want the Data object be. 
       //But I want it to fill in programmatically. 
       // It displays in my view when I hardcode it inside the ngOnInit. But obvs that's not good.


        this.data = [
            {
                tabLabel: '1st Label',
                template: this.orderDetails
            },
            {
                tabLabel: '2nd Label',
                template: this.anotherTemp
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

I expect the `Data` object to be dynamically filled with a new object like this `{tabLabel: 'My new label', template: 'my_new_template'`

If this is not possible, suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.

The problem is that you're trying to push your ViewChild references into your array in the `constructor()`, before they have been created in the page, so the selectors can't select anything yet.

Instead, do it in the [`ngOnInit()` life-cycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), as you did manually, which did work.

So something like:

```
// Illustration only, you can delete empty constructors
constructor () {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.data.push({ tabLabel: 'newlabel', template: this.orderDetails });
}
```

As a general rule of thumb: the `constructor()` in Angular is used basically only for initializing variables to known (static) values or injecting class references (like Services). You can't touch the DOM in the constructor, because the template hasn't yet been rendered when that runs. That's what lifecycle hooks are for.

As a side-note: instead of manually maintaining that object array, perhaps [`@ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) would be useful.

Comment: Thank you! Yes moving `this.data.push({ tabLabel: 'newlabel', template: this.orderDetails });` into the `ngOnInit` did push the new object into the `data` array.

But is there a way to push w/out having to manually write a new object inside `this.data.push()` ?

Comment: @LailaAli No, because that object is the type `<ITabData>` which requires those specific fields, so you need to declare them. So you're pushing that object (which is a [TypeScript Interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) ) into your array.

Comment: so if I did not have a `type` or wrote it as an `interface`, then would I still have to enter each object manually? 

So as it currently stands, if I had 100 new tabs and templates, I would have to add _each_ `object` individually?

Comment: @LailaAli Yes, which is why I suggested looking at `ViewChildren` (plural), which creates an array of `ElementRefs` for you based on a query. Perhaps you could use that instead of an `ITabData[]`. The problem is the architectural need to have that `data` array in the first place. What's it for? Do you really have a single page with hundreds of tabs?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the last line in your original comment regarding `@ViewChildren`.

I will read more on that! 

I am creating a reusable `Tab Component`. And the parent decides how many `tabs` and what `template` goes with what tab.

Comment: @LailaAli That's what I surmised from your variable naming. Good luck! Come back and post more questions on more topics if you need to!